# Why is the list in the class attribute still a class attribute after instantiation, not an instance attribute?

Tags: python, class, instance

I have a class with a property and a list with empty values. When two instances of a and b are generated and elements are added to the property, it is found that the property is not instantiated. Use id to view a.property and b.property. The memory address is the same. Why?

How can the `property attribute` become an `instance attribute`?

My code example is as follows:

```
class MyClass:
    property = []

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def append(self, value):
        self.property.append(value)


a = MyClass()
b = MyClass()
a.append(1)
print(a.property)
b.append(1)

print(a.property)
print(b.property)

print(id(a.property))
print(id(b.property))
```

The result is:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1]
1866383694784
1866383694784
```

The result I respected:

```
[1]
[1]
[1]
```

Comment: In your own words, when you write `def __init__(self):`, what do you think that is for? Also, what attempts did you make to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) the question yourself? For example, did you try putting `python instance attribute` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+instance+attribute)? Stack Overflow is not a tutorial centre.

Comment: You don't need class methods to change values of class variables

Comment: Do not edit your question to ask a whole new question. But again, you can easily answer this by doing the kind of research that is expected of you here.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I also know that it can be defined in `def __init__(self)`. I have different uses for my class attributes and instance attributes, and other assignments are omitted in `def __init__(self)`. I came to starkoverflow to ask questions with questions.I feel that what I am asking is not a new question, but an inaccurate description of my previous question.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel In this way, I first change the question back to the original state, and then ask again.

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users, and if you cannot solve the problem yourself by trying internet searches like the one that I already linked you, then start over with a new question.

Comment: Please don't edit answers into questions. You can always post (and even accept!) your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case `property = []` is a class variable, which is shared with all instances of your class. I asume, that you don't want to share the value of `property = []` with other classes. That means you need a instance variable, which can be defined like down below.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.property = []

    def append(self, value):
        self.property.append(value)
```

This should give you your expected output, sheers!

Comment: Is there no other way besides defining it in  `def __init__ (self)`?

Comment: @jaried No, all instance variables must be in the ``__init__` function. Is that a problem or why do you ask?

Comment: But some attributes are defined in the class and not defined in `def __init__(self)`. The instance is equivalent to copying the attributes of the class instead of using the attributes of the class. Why?

Comment: @jaried As I said there is a differnce between `class variables` and `instance variables`. Class variables are declared outside of the `__init__` function and are shared by all class instances. Instance variables are inside the `__init__` function and aren't shared by the class instances. That means changes to instance variables only change the instance itself.

Comment: I revised my question.

Comment: Look at my last modified code, I did not define the property in `def __init__(self)`, but the modification of the instance's property does not affect the class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you don't declare `property` inside of the `__init__` function.
`__init__` is being called every time a new instance of the object is created, so I guess this is what you are looking for.
Try applying the following changes to your class:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.property = []

    def append(self, value):
        self.property.append(value)
```

Comment: I revised my question.

Comment: I think I might know the answer. A list is like an array, and if you have experienced a low-level programming language like C/CPP you should know that the value of an array in the computer's memory is actually the memory address of the first value it holds. On the other hand, the value of numbers (`int` for example in other languages) is directly stored in the address being given by the computer. The point is, I think that because you used a list before, the memory address stayed the same, but now because you are assigning numbers as values, they each gain a different memory address.

Comment: I hope I was able to make everything clear, I just ran out of characters... –

Comment: Oh, I see you have changed the question back to the original way it was... I'll still leave this comment here, just in case

Comment: I found the reason why. Thanks for your answer.